# Expressão regular para filtrar o primeiro parágrafo entre tags usando PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

**Preciso extrair o primeiro parágrafo de um código HTML usando Expressões Regulares.**

**O Objetivo: pegar apenas o conteúdo destacado em verde:**
[image: O Objetivo é pegar apenas o texto conforme a imagem]

**Código HTML**

```
<div class="text">                          <p><span style="font-size:16px">As notas do Exame Nacional do Ensino Médio (Enem) 2017 foram divulgadas nesta quinta-feira (18). O resultado deve ser consultado individualmente: para isso, os candidatos devem acessar a Página do Participante (https://enem.inep.gov.br/participante/) e incluir CPF e a senha cadastrada. </span></p>    <p><span style="font-size:16px">O resultado dos treineiros só será divulgado em 19 de março. Na mesma data, o Ministério da Educação também vai disponibilizar os chamados "espelhos da redação", que são a cópia digitalizada dos textos e as justificativas para as notas. </span></p>    <p><span style="font-size:16px">Nesta quinta, o Ministério da Educação (MEC) divulgou o balanço sobre o desempenho dos candidatos na edição de 2017 do exame. Apenas 53 alunos tiraram nota mil na redação, porém a nota média subiu de 541,9 para 558. Neste ano, os candidatos escreveram sobre o tema "Desafios para a formação educacional de surdos no Brasil".</span></p>    <p><span style="font-size:16px">Com a nota do Enem 2017, os estudantes podem concorrer a uma vaga em uma universidade pública que tenha aderido ao Sistema de Seleção Unificada (Sisu) 2018. As vagas já podem ser consultadas. Serão 130 instituições no Brasil - 30 estaduais e 100 federais -, que ofertarão 239.601 vagas na graduação.</span></p>
```

**Estou tentando filtrar no PHP com preg_match_all**

```
$filtroregex = "/<p><span style=\"font\-size:16px\">(.*?)<\/span><\/p>/s"; 
preg_match_all($filtroregex, $htmlcode, $resultado);
echo $resultado[1][0];
```

**Mas sempre está retornando todos os parágrafos.**

Comment: Já utilizou `var_dump($resultado);` para obter as respostas? Já pensou em utilizar o `XPath` ou `DOMDocument` ?

Comment: var_dump Sim, daí tenho esse último filtro que é pegar o primeiro parágrafo.  
  
[Analise a Regex aqui](https://regex101.com/r/6l6PRW/1)

Answer (score 1):

Se o conteúdo que você esta querendo pegar não for de uma pagina renderizada por uma engine de template ou pre-processada por JS, esse código poderá te ajudar.

```
<?php  
$curl = curl_init();  
$url = "http://suapagina.html";  
curl_setopt_array($curl, [  
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,  
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
]);  

// Pega o conteudo da pagina HTML  
$response = curl_exec($curl);  

// Pega as mensagens de erro  
$err = [  
    'curl_error' => [  
        'error_code'    => curl_errno($curl),  
        'erro_message'  => curl_error($curl)  
    ]  
];  

$dom = new DOMDocument();  
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);  

// Carrega o conteudo da pagina dentro de um objeto  
$dom->loadHTML($response);  

// Descarta os whitespaces    
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;    

// Busca todas as incidencias da tag  
$results = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span');  

// Fecha a conexao  
curl_close($curl);  

foreach($results as $result)  
{  
    echo $result->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;  
}
```

Comment: **Não funcionou mesmo alterando alguns parâmetros**  
Segue o erro:    
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string in /home/a_dom.php on line 40 (foreach)

Comment: Eu alterei o código. Havia me esquecido de colocar o parâmetro 'nodeValue' na hora de imprimir o resultado. Dê uma olhada lá.

Comment: Se a tag utilizada possuir o atributo **id** definido, você pode pegar o conteúdo através desses comandos, sem a necessidade de percorrer um array:  
  
`...  
$results = $dom->getElementById('<VALOR DO PARAMETRO ID>');  
echo $results->nodeValue;`

Answer (score 1):

**Depois de muito pesquisar sobre Regex**

**Achei a solução**

```
/<p><span style=\"font\-size:16px\">(.*?)<\/span><\/p>/s
```

**[confira aqui](https://regex101.com/r/6l6PRW/3)**